# Extracting text via Javascript

Tags: javascript, grep

I need to do what I expect to be some simple text parsing thru JavaScript of some HTML and additional text.

I can already get the text for the classes, but I can't extract the text from the first `<div>`

```
<div>NRG Software, LLC.</div>
<div class="street-address">10437 innovation dr #311</div>
<span class="locality">milwaukee</span>,
<span class="region">WI</span>
<span class="postal-code">53226</span>
<div class="country-name">United States</div>
```

I've got another chunk that looks like this and I'd like to get the Order #.

```
<p class="header-tools">
    <a class="button-medium button-medium-grey print-view" href="http://www.zzz.com/your/orders/26565180?show_panel=true" data-stylesheet="receipt-print-receipt.css">
        <span>Print Order</span>
    </a>
</p>
<div class="print-logo print-only">
    <img src="/images/logo-print.png" alt="zzz">
</div>
<h2>Order #26565180 on Dec 7, 2010</h2>
```

Comment: Add an id to the <div> to get <div id=company>NRG Software, LLC.</div> and you get use `var company = document.getElementById('company').innerHTML;`

Comment: i have no control over the html otherwise i'd add an id

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var mytext = document.getElementById("street-address").textContent;
```

or to get the HTML:

```
var myhtml = document.getElementById("street-address").innerHTML;
```

You should to add an id to any elements who's content you need to parse.

UPDATE:
IE7 and back do not support textContent so you need to use the following to support old versions of IE:

```
var myhtml = document.getElementById("street-address").innerText;
```

Comment: You should be aware that textcontent doesn't work in legacy browsers, a safer way is to grab the textNode child of the street-address element and get that node's value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the text nodes concatenated together with...

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],
    text = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/kbQ6A/).

Alternatively, you can build the text yourself by recursively iterating over text nodes...

```
var getText = function me(element) {
    var text = '',
        children = element.childNodes,
        childrenLength = children.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < childrenLength; i++) {

        if (children[i].nodeType == 1) {
            text += me(children[i]);

        } else if (children[i].nodeType == 3) {
            text += children[i].data;

        }

    }
    return text;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/nLmPc/).